# If Ienumerable List returns 1 object can I convert it to an object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ienumerable

If

`Ienumerable<Person> per = _serviceToGetPerson();` happens to only return one 'per' is it possible to assign it to a Person.

Person p = per.???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)/[FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Person p = per.FirstOrDefault();
```

[`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would return the first Object from the list or `null` if the List is empty.

You can also use Single / SingleOrDefault, if you are expecting only one item back from the list or only one or null *(for `SingleOrDefault`)*

Make sure that you have included `using System.Linq;` namespace

Comment: you cant use .FirstOrDefault with iEnumerable..what is? .GetEnumerator().Current;

Comment: @John, Yes you can use FirstOrDefault with IEnumerable. How it works see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3700187/961113)

Comment: Make sure you include the `System.Linq` namespace.

Comment: @MailmanOdd, Yes that could be the reason OP is not seeing `FirstOrDefault`